# Remove duplicate line based on column for fixed length file

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a fixed length file having primary key from 1-8. there is no delimiter. I want to eliminate duplicates by eliminating second occurrence. Look for solutions in unix.

File looks like this:

```
A00991CCAGXCD K 9999PHLX CANADIAN DOLLAR        F
G0084W10%AEURN  4612EURONAV NV ANTWERPEN        F
D1819089%ADB    6021DEUTSCHE BANK AG            F
G0084W10GAADNT  6799ADIENT PLC                  F
D1F19089NADB    6021DEUTSCHE BANK AG            F
```

Output extected is:

```
A00991CCAGXCD K 9999PHLX CANADIAN DOLLAR        F
G0084W10%AEURN  4612EURONAV NV ANTWERPEN        F
D1819089%ADB    6021DEUTSCHE BANK AG            F
D1F19089NADB    6021DEUTSCHE BANK AG            F
```

Comment: ITYM fixed width, not fixed length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '!a[substr($1,1,8)]++' file
```

The output:

```
A00991CCAGXCD K 9999PHLX CANADIAN DOLLAR F
G0084W10%AEURN 4612EURONAV NV ANTWERPEN F
D1819089%ADB 6021DEUTSCHE BANK AG F
D1F19089NADB 6021DEUTSCHE BANK AG F
```

---

- `substr($1,1,8)` - returns 8-character-long substring from the 1st field `$1` (starting from the 1st char)
- `!a[...]++` - considering only the first occurence of unique array index

Comment: Thanks, this solution helped and its very simple.